# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/local/var/run/mysql55/mysqld.sock' (2),

Tags: mysql

Can anyone please help !! following similar queries on stackoverflow did not help.

I get the below error when I start mysql (by typing `mysql` in the terminal).

More info:

1. I updated macports before installing MySQL (`sudo port selfupdate`).
2. I'm on mac OSX, installed MySQL via macports by following the [instructions.](http://jackal.livejournal.com/2160464.html)
3. I am trying to use mysql database for a django project.
4. I noticed that I have couple of versions of mysql installed, could the errors be due to this ?

After searching for a day on internet to resolve this issue, I am trying my best option by posting it here.  I'm a newbie to programming, so please do question if I did not make anything clear.

Comment: This question isn't appropriate for Stack Overflow as it doesn't have to do with programming.  You might check with http://serverfault.com or http://superuser.com instead.

Comment: Check if your current user have the permission to access mysql files.If not, change the owner of mysql folder. Use ll -a to see if your current user have the permission. Use sudo chown -R yourSqlFolderPath to change the owner of mysql.Hope it helps.